# How to make a never ending course?

Tags: stepmania

I created a .crs file and put this in it:

```
#COURSE:Endless 6-8;
#REPEAT:YES;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
#SONG:*:6..8;
```

But when I play it, it always plays the same one song over and over again. How do I get it to play random 6-8 songs forever?

I'm using Stepmania 5.

Comment: For reference, the .crs here looks identical to [this one](http://t-a-w.blogspot.ca/2007/04/endless-dancing-with-stepmania-crs.html)

Comment: @skovacs1: Sure is... I should have credited him. But it doesn't work as he describes. At least not in Stepmania 5.

Comment: I took a brief look at [the source to parse crs files](https://code.google.com/p/stepmania/source/browse/src/CourseLoaderCRS.cpp). It parses the string to set the meter criteria on lines 280-282. `new_entry.bSecret = true;` is commented out on line 218, but I'm not sure what that does at a glance. Your crs seems to check out with the parser anyhow. The only explanations that come to mind are a problem deeper in the code or maybe you only have just the one song that meets those meter criteria (seems doubtful). If you're confident it's a code issue, I'd try Stepmania forums or help.

Comment: The one song that it plays continuously, is it always the same song every time you run the course or is it a random song each time you run the course, just stuck repeating endlessly? This could help to narrow the scope of the problem.

Comment: @skovacs1: It's a different song each time I run the course. It doesn't need to be endless if I can queue up 50-100 songs, but if I take off `#REPEAT:YES` I can't find the course anymore. It's not in "endless" nor "extended" modes. I'll try the forums... doesn't look terribly lively in there. Thanks for your help.